# Providing types explicitly in Go var declaraction fails while implicit works

Tags: variables, go, variable-declaration

I am new to go and currently going through the `go tool tour`.

While on the **Short variable declarations** section, I modified the sample code to look like this?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i, j int = 1, 2
    k := 3
    var c bool, python string = true, "test"

    fmt.Println(i, j, k, c, python)
}
```

However, then I run the above code, I get the error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./compile233.go:8:12: syntax error: unexpected comma at end of statement
```

However, if I remove the types from the `var` declaration like the following:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i, j int = 1, 2
    k := 3
    var c, python = true, "test"

    fmt.Println(i, j, k, c, python)
}
```

It works.

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the first example, and the error seems a bit misleading to me. Could anyone explain what I did wrong and why I'm getting the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable declaration statement is defined as

```
VarDecl     = "var" ( VarSpec | "(" { VarSpec ";" } ")" ) .
VarSpec     = IdentifierList ( Type [ "=" ExpressionList ] | "=" ExpressionList ) .
```

which means that if you want to declare multiple variables with type specified explicitly in a single statement they all must have the same type. And that type must come after the identifier list.

So

```
var foo, bar bool // is valid
var foo bool, bar bool // is not (only one type qualifier is allowed)
```

Reference:

- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations

Comment: How does implicit work then though, because even though types have not been mentioned, it is still multiple types in a single declaration?

Comment: @AyushGupta it works because syntax allows it. "it is still multiple types in a single declaration" --- and it's fine. It is only one type qualifier that is allowed.